# Error in Saving NLTK HMM

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, hidden-markov-models

I was trying to save HMM Tagger of NLTK as follows, with Pickle. But it is giving me error as follows,
Please suggest me a solution.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import pickle
>>> brown_a = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()[:300]
>>> hmm_tagger=nltk.HiddenMarkovModelTagger.train(brown_a)
>>> sent = nltk.corpus.brown.sents()[400]
>>> hmm_tagger.tag(sent)
[(u'He', u'PPS'), (u'is', u'BEZ'), (u'not', u'*'), (u'interested', u'VBN'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'being', u'NN'), (u'named', u'IN'), (u'a', u'AT'), (u'full-time', u'JJ'), (u'director', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')]
>>> f = open('my_tagger.pickle', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(hmm_tagger, f)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.dump(hmm_tagger, f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1376, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 669, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 669, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function estimator at 0x0575F6F0>: it's not found as nltk.tag.hmm.estimator
>>>
```

I am on Python2.7.11 with NLTK3.1 on MS-Windows10.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to pickle the model? Training on the brown corpus is extremely fast. And if you want a better part-of-speech tagger, consider looking at https://spacy.io/ which is easy to use in Python has great pickling support and produces state-of-the art results. Indeed, HMM taggers are really bad nowadays.

Anyway, this is a NLTK bug. Three options:

1. Report the bug to NLTK and/or fix it by moving the estimator function outside of the _train function to put in the module (so that pickle can find it in `nltk.tag.hmm.estimator`
2. Provide your own estimator function so that pickle finds it in your own module
3. Use a pickle alternative such as dill or cloudpickle: they may be able to handle this estimator function.

Here's how to dump your tagger using dill:

```
import nltk
import dill

brown_a = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()[:300]
hmm_tagger=nltk.HiddenMarkovModelTagger.train(brown_a)
sent = nltk.corpus.brown.sents()[400]
hmm_tagger.tag(sent)
# [(u'He', u'PPS'), (u'is', u'BEZ'), (u'not', u'*'), (u'interested', u'VBN'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'being', u'NN'), (u'named', u'IN'), (u'a', u'AT'), (u'full-time', u'JJ'), (u'director', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')]

with open('my_tagger.dill', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(hmm_tagger, f)
```

Now you can load the tagger:

```
import dill

with open('my_tagger.dill', 'rb') as f:
    hmm_tagger = dill.load(f)

hmm_tagger.tag(sent)
# [(u'He', u'PPS'), (u'is', u'BEZ'), (u'not', u'*'), (u'interested', u'VBN'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'being', u'NN'), (u'named', u'IN'), (u'a', u'AT'), (u'full-time', u'JJ'), (u'director', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')]
```